# Google Custom search API. Unable to get featured snippet box result

Tags: google-custom-search

I am trying to use the custom search API for integrating the search functionality in my application. The results which I am getting using the custom search API does not contain in "featured snippet box" and "Knowledge Cards". How to get all the search results that we get from the google tool bar(google.com)?

Comment: got anything on this?